# JQuery Finding a Div using parents

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table full of checkboxes.  Each row is one event and each checkbox is a task that needs to be completed for that event.  I want to be able to replace the checkbox with the initials of the User who selected it.  I also want to be able to choose the div below the checkbox thats clicked so I can reveal it because it contains my initials.  Also Im using Ruby on Rails.

```
<td class='completed_box'  id='complete_raw_footage_<%= check_list.id %>'>
        <%= f.check_box :raw_footage_check, :class => 'task_check', :id => 'check_list_raw_footage_check_' + check_list.id.to_s, :category => 'raw_footage', :check_list_id => check_list.id, :style => ("display:none" if check_list.raw_footage_user_id != nil) %>    
        <div class='initials' style="<%= 'display:none;' if check_list.raw_footage_user_id == nil %>">
            <div id='raw_footage_<%= check_list.id %>' title='<%= check_list.event.name %>' class='hidden_dialog'>
                    <b>Task Completed:</b> Raw Footage Recieved <br />
                    <b>Task Completed By:</b> <%= check_list.raw_footage_user_id.name rescue current_user.name %><br />
                    <b>Task Completed At:</b> <%= check_list.raw_footage_date.strftime("%F %r") rescue Time.now.strftime("%F %r") %>
            </div>
            <%= check_list.raw_footage_user_id.initials rescue current_user.initials%> <br />
            <%= check_list.raw_footage_date.strftime("%-m/%d") rescue Time.now.strftime("%-m/%d") %>
        </div>
    </td>
```

so when the checkbox with the class 'task_check' is clicked it will find ONLY the next class 'initials' and change the css to display:inline.  If you need anymore information please let me know.

```
$('.completed_box').children('.initials').css('display','inline')
```

That is what i used originally but it turns every div w/ the class initials to display:inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` as your starting point and you can use `.closest()` to find a particular parent and `.find()` from there to find another subordinate under that same parent.  Using `.closest()` and `.find()` are less brittle to changes if the HTML layout is later changed a bit since they don't rely on exactly positions or exactly numbers of parents - they only rely on being in the same branch of the hierarchy.

I'm not sure I follow your templated HTML exactly, but perhaps something like this:

```
$(this).closest(".completed_box").find(".initials").css('display','inline')
```

Comment: Using `.closest()` and .`find()` make your code more tolerant of HTML layout changes than using .parent()` and `.children()`.  For example if someone added one more `div` layer in order to change formatting, `.parent()` and `.children()` could break.

Comment: It worked perfect thank you very much.  So just so I understand this right whats happening is its going from this, the checkmark, to the 'completed_div' above it because its the closest one, then finding the first initials after that?  So basically it goes up one then down to initials?  I'm still fairly new to using extensive javascript / jquery so any help is GREATLY appreciated

Comment: @user1977840 - `.closest()` finds the first parent that matches a selector (going up the parent chain).   `.find()` finds all subordinate elements from the starting point in the DOM tree that match a selector.  This logic is very useful for finding other elements in my same branch of the DOM tree which is the problem you have here. This is a very common design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the next element

```
$('.task_check').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.is(':checked') ) {
        $(this).next('.initials').css('display','inline')
    } else {
        $(this).next('.initials').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: This would work perfect but I hide the checkbox once its clicked so it wouldn't be 'checked' after one try.  But thank you for your idea there's no way you could have known that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS too.

```
.task_check:checked + .initials{display:inline-block;}
```

According to W3School, it should be supported by every major browser.